# Trying to remove a white space from my page

Tags: html, css

As i'm making my first website there's this white space in my page i'm trying to remove but i can't , i tried the position and few settings but it doesn't seem to work , i even edited few of my already wroten code.
Any help will be good.
Thanks

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibRTR.jpg)

[The github project](https://github.com/AmrouHab/stackoverflow-help)

I have 2 files 1 for html and 1 for css for now 
Here's my html file

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Template_Header_Footer.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Header Last version (sans responsive)</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <picture>
      <source srcset="images/Logo.png" media="(max-width: 640px)">
      <source srcset="images/Logo.png" media="(max-width: 1500px)">
      <img id="logo" src="images/Logo.png" style"width:40%;">
    </picture>
    <picture>
      <source srcset="images/paysage.jpg" media="(max-width: 640px)">
      <source srcset="images/paysage.jpg" media="(max-width: 1500px)">
      <img id="paysage" src="images/paysage.jpg" style"width:40%;">
    </picture>
    <p>Syndicat CTFC 34</p>
    <center>
      <h1>Syndicat Constructif, Partenaire du Dialogue Social<h1>
    </center>
    <section class="navigation">
      <div class="nav-container">
        <nav>
          <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
          <ul class="nav-list">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Connaitre la CFTC</a>
              <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#!">Histoire</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Valeurs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Identité</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Syndicat CFTC-FPT 34</a>
              <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#!">Organisation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Rôle et définition</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Vie Professionnelle</a>
              <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#!">Formation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Statut</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Carrière</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Temps de Travail</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Congés</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Vie Pratique</a>
              <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#!">Action Logement</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Pensions Alimentaires impayées</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Prime d'activité</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Apprentissage</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#!">Activités</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Actualités</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Presse</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Adhésion</a>
              <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#!">Les + adhérents</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Espace adhérents</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Nous rejoindre</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Coordonnées</a>
              <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#!">Syndicat CFTC-FPT 34</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">UD34</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Fédération CFTC FPT</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </section>
  </header>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($) { // Begin jQuery
    $(function() { // DOM ready
      // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
      $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
        $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
        // Close one dropdown when selecting another
        $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
      // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
      $('html').click(function() {
        $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
      });
      // Toggle open and close nav styles on click
      $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
        $('nav ul').slideToggle();
      });
      // Hamburger to X toggle
      $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle('active');
      });
    }); // end DOM ready
  })(jQuery); // end jQuery
</script>

</html>
```

And that's my CSS Files :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "oswald";
  src: url("fonts\oswald.regular.ttf");
  font-family: "lato";
  src: url("fonts\Lato-Regular.ttf");
  font-family: "playfairdisplay";
  src: url("fonts\PlayfairDisplaySC-Regular.otf");
}

.navigation {
  height: 70px;
  background: #028893;
}

.brand a, .brand a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  float: none;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a, nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #028893;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: oswald;
}

nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:visited:hover {
  background: #1a6066;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after, nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}

nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

/* Mobile navigation */
.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  /* position: absolute; */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #262626;
  /* height: 70px; */
  width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }

  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }

  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }

  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }

  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

article {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Partie pour le logo et la photo et la phrase  */
#logo {
  float: left;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
}

header p {
  font-family: oswald;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 80px;
}

#paysage {
  float: right;
  height: 400px;
  width: 1520px;
}

header h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0px solid #01B2C0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #01B2C0;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: lato;
  /* position: relative; */
  bottom: 80px;
  width: auto;
  /* height: 33px; */
  padding-top: 25px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a _proper_ [mre], here, and not half of it on github. (Without the actual image files, your problem does not appear to be properly reproducible, but it should not be our job now, to fish them out of your repo and place them somewhere where we can run the whole thing live then.)

Comment: @CBroe i know , i'll try to make a reproducible minimal version

Answer (score -1):

Seems that the height of logo is bigger than the banner height.Manage Logo Height.

Comment: Hi @Dipika - When providing answers please provide solutions to the problem, not just general guidance. You can post code to show how it should be done. Thank you.